# Want to short the query

Tags: mysql, join

I have the query, which is giving correct result, but, I am sure there are other way to do so, having same conditions repeated.

Can anybody help me to reduce the complexity of the query.

Query using these mysql parameters:-

```
SELECT avai.account_visit_account_info_pk                             AS Account_ID,
       mb.NAME                                                        AS Client_Name,
       mb.fullname                                                    AS Client_Full_Name,
       avai.account_name                                              AS Account_Name,
       mc.NAME                                                        AS Asset_City,
       Format(( bfd.finance_value ), 'en_IN')                         AS Reserve_Price,
       Format(( bfd.finance_value ) * 10 / 100, 'en_IN')              AS EMD_Value,
       Ifnull(Concat(CASE
                       WHEN mpc.parent = 4 THEN 'Residential'
                       WHEN mpc.parent = 5 THEN 'Commercial'
                       WHEN mpc.parent = 6 THEN 'Industrial'
                       WHEN mpc.parent = 7 THEN 'Agricultural'
                     END, '/', mpc.category_name), mpc.category_name) Asset_Category,
       Concat(ud.first_name, ' ', ud.last_name)                       AS ADM_Name,
       Concat(udd.first_name, ' ', udd.last_name)                     AS MKT_Name,
       mcc.NAME                                                       AS ADM_City,
       ms.NAME                                                        AS ADM_State,
       mz.NAME                                                        AS ADM_Zone,
       bec.e_auction_from                                             AS Auction_Date,
       bfdd.finance_value                                             AS Sold_Price
FROM   account_branch_visit abv
       JOIN mst_product_category mpc
         ON mpc.mst_product_category_pk = abv.mst_product_category_pk
       JOIN mst_bank mb
         ON abv.mst_bank_pk = mb.mst_bank_pk
       JOIN banking_financial_details bfd
         ON abv.account_branch_visit_pk = bfd.account_branch_visit_pk
            AND bfd.mst_financial_pk IN ( 33 )
       LEFT JOIN banking_financial_details bfdd
              ON abv.account_branch_visit_pk = bfdd.account_branch_visit_pk
                 AND bfd.mst_financial_pk IN ( 38 )
       JOIN mst_city mc
         ON mc.mst_city_pk = avai.mst_city_pk
       JOIN mst_city mcc
         ON mcc.mst_city_pk = avai.mst_city_pk
       JOIN mst_state ms
         ON ms.mst_state_pk = mcc.mst_state_pk
       JOIN mst_zone mz
         ON mz.mst_zone_pk = ms.mst_zone_pk
       JOIN case_allocation ca
         ON ca.account_branch_visit_pk = avai.account_branch_visit_pk
            AND ca.mst_activity_pk = 21
       JOIN case_allocation caa
         ON caa.account_branch_visit_pk = avai.account_branch_visit_pk
            AND caa.mst_activity_pk = 18
       JOIN user_detail ud
         ON ud.user_detail_pk = ca.assignedto
       JOIN user_detail udd
         ON udd.user_detail_pk = caa.assignedto
       JOIN banking_event_calender bec
         ON bec.account_branch_visit_pk = avai.account_branch_visit_pk
            AND ( abv.closed_reasons_pk IS NULL
                   OR abv.closed_reasons_pk = 16 )
            AND abv.isdeleted = '0'
WHERE  avai.account_branch_visit_pk = '1301';
```

Comment: Your query ends with `WHERE  avai.account_branch_visit_pk = '1301'`. Where is the table (or alias)  `avai`  introduced?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what the exact intent of the query is, so I will provide some technical nuances, without actually understanding your data model or goal. The `select` clause provides you some columns and you probably need it. So, what I'm looking for are duplicate table joins. Some of them are necessary, some of them are unnecessary.

## banking_financial_details

You `join` and `left join` this table with different ideas. You use both of them, so I assume this is necessary.

## mst_city

This is obviously unnecessarily duplicating:

```
   JOIN mst_city mc
     ON mc.mst_city_pk = avai.mst_city_pk
   JOIN mst_city mcc
     ON mcc.mst_city_pk = avai.mst_city_pk
```

Remove the second `JOIN` and `ON` clauses from the above and replace all usages of `mcc` to `mc` in the query.

## case_allocation

You `join` this table twice, but with different ids and you then join the corresponding `user_detail` to both and both `user_detail` instances are being used, so this is probably necessary.

## user_detail

Since this duplicated `join` seems to be used in the `select`, it's probably necessary.

## Summary

We have found an unnecessary `join` that can be removed. Further shortening of the query may be possible, but we would need to know more about your task and database to determine further improvements.

Comment: Actually, I have to prepare a report in which all field in select query is require, Since I am not very much known of database query, I am trying to achieve in any way.

Comment: When you have a complex problem, you will (most of the times!) also end up with a complex SQL query.   The current query does not seem to be very complex, but it is unknown what the query should achieve, any optimizations that can be done using current info are done in this answer.